# The right way to write a if-can-add check method before create a complete object?

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

I have several object implement with polymorphism . Before add it to the container , I have to check if the status of container and values of the corresponding object is valid to allow adding the object, the step is:

1) Use the object's virtual method to do the test

2) If test is passed, create the object, add it to the container

**My problem is:**
In the first step, I need the virtual method of the object, so I have to create 
the object. This can be a resource waste if the test failed since the process of construct the object is costly.

Some solution is :

1. Make the test method public static, but seemed not work with polymorphism .
2. Make a overloading constructor take no params, and use this object to do the test. This way, I have to provide two constructor, there are two shortcomings :

   a. I'm afraid the misuse of this incomplete object through the whole project by other programers.

   b. I provide a simple factory method, If there are two constructors, I have to write another factory method to get the different object, these duplicate codes can be a nightmare.
3. The brute force way is to provide some other independent method outside of the object, pass the context info to it, and use these method to do the test.

What is the proper way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you need a builder pattern since you are about to construct object step by step.

Another solution is to use strategy pattern if you have a kind of if-else decision to create each object. So you can add to your container the right object according to your algorithm of creating